# Unable to parse array string

Tags: php, arrays, json

I've generated an array like below.But unable to parse it in json_encode.Am I missing anything here? please let me know.

PHP code :

```
<?php

$i=0;
$result = shell_exec('scripts/fetch_script.sh');

foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $result) as $line)
{
    parse_str($line);

}

$stat = "array(";
    $lines = file('parameter.file');
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $v = explode('|', strtoupper($line));
        $str = '$v[1]';
        eval("\$str = \"$str\";");
        eval("\$str = \"$str\";");
        $calc = eval("return round(($str),2);");

        $stat .="'$v[0]' => $calc,";


    }
    $stat .=");";
echo json_encode($stat);
?>
```

But output shows like Below which is not in json format:

```
"array('QUERY_CACHE_USAGE' => 0,'DISK_TMP_TABLES_USAGE' => 1.52,'QUERY_CACHE_USAGE' => 0,'DISK_TMP_TABLES_USAGE' => 1.52,'QUERY_CACHE_USAGE' => 0,'DISK_TMP_TABLES_USAGE' => 1.52,'QUERY_CACHE_USAGE' => 0,'DISK_TMP_TABLES_USAGE' => 1.52,'QUERY_CACHE_USAGE' => 0,'DISK_TMP_TABLES_USAGE' => 1.52,'QUERY_CACHE_USAGE' => 0,'DISK_TMP_TABLES_USAGE' => 1.52,'QUERY_CACHE_USAGE' => 0,'DISK_TMP_TABLES_USAGE' => 1.52,'QUERY_CACHE_USAGE' => 0,'DISK_TMP_TABLES_USAGE' => 1.52,'QUERY_CACHE_USAGE' => 0,'DISK_TMP_TABLES_USAGE' => 1.52,'QUERY_CACHE_USAGE' => 0,'DISK_TMP_TABLES_USAGE' => 1.52,'QUERY_CACHE_USAGE' => 0,'DISK_TMP_TABLES_USAGE' => 1.52,'QUERY_CACHE_USAGE' => 0,'DISK_TMP_TABLES_USAGE' => 1.52,);"
```

Comment: **$stat** is string it is not array, try with **var_dump($stat);** and test it

Comment: Used  var_dump in script ,still facing this issue.
..
....
var_dump($stat);
echo json_encode($stat);


below is the output.
https://jpst.it/181m8

Comment: json_encode($stat, true), try to add true in parameter json_encode

Comment: getting same output  for var_dump($stat);
echo json_encode($stat,true); Here is the output --- https://jpst.it/181oG

Comment: `json_encode` works for an array, not string. Change your code to make array instead of string

Comment: Why are you using `eval()` for everything? And why is not "script" not return proper JSON to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

The array you're trying to convert to JSON has duplicates, which means that it'll only keep the last occurrence of a duplicated key. For example :

```
var_dump(['foo' => 'bar', 'foo' => 2]); //displays ["foo"] => int(2)
```

Since you're already using `eval` you might as well also use it to evaluate the string into an array :

```
echo json_encode(eval('return ' . $raw), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Do know however that "eval" is one letter away from "evil". Unless you trust the contents of parameter.file, I'd avoid relying on it. I recommend parsing the file manually instead of relying on eval.